# Delete message using paho javascript client

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

How to delete a message or get message timestamp using paho JS client from `activemq` broker?

I could not found anyway of deleting message from JS paho client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of deleting a message in MQTT, once sent it's sent.

The closest would be to clear a retained message and you do this by publishing a message with a null/empty payload.

There is also no timestamp in a MQTT message unless you add one to the payload yourself.

Comment: I didnt get meaning of `message with a null/empty payload.` and `add timestamp to the payload`

Comment: The MQTT protocol has no where to store a timestamp, the only way to get one would to include it in the payload of your message. If you publish a retained message to a topic with no payload (empty byte array) it will clear the previous retained message

Comment: can't we delete a specific message?

Comment: There is no way to delete a message once published